# ¿Cómo debo cifrar un atributo password si uso una variable request en Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Actualmente me estoy iniciando en Laravel y estoy tratando de desarrollar mi módulo de usuario. Ya desarrolle el CRUD completo, he activado el Auth de Laravel, cree un controlador Users...

Se me está presentando que al registrar un usuario normalmente lo realiza sin problemas pero cuando se crea un usuario por el CRUD no me está cifrando el atributo password por tal motivo al querer acceder no me lo permite, me muestra el mensaje de que las credenciales no existen en los registros...

Tengo esto en el controlador para crear usuarios por el crud:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'username'=> 'required',
        'rol'=> 'required',
        'status' => 'required',
        'email'=> 'required',
        'password'=> 'required',
    ]);

    User::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('users.index')
                    ->with('success','user created successfully');
}
```

¿Qué debo colocar para que me cifre el password?

Laravel trae por defecto el controlador de register pero usa variable array:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Nota: los demás campos los he colocado en el register porque están en null en la migración ya que no son obligatorios en mi ejercicio.

¿Está mal lo que estoy haciendo con request? ¿Qué me recomiendan?

Answer (score 1):

Asi  | No estoy seguro que funcione pero es una idea !

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'username'=> 'required',
        'rol'=> 'required',
        'status' => 'required',
        'email'=> 'required',
        'password'=> 'required',
    ]);

    User::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'last_name' => $request['last_name'],
        'username'=> $request['username'],
        'rol'=> $request['rol'],
        'status' => $request['status'],
        'email'=> $request['email'],
        'password'=> bcrypt($request['password']),
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('users.index')
                    ->with('success','user created successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ¿esta mal lo que estoy haciendo con request? ¿que me recomiendan?

Sí y no, tienes una muy buena aproximación de cómo controlar los datos de la `Request`, pero debes de tener en cuenta algo; si tu no validas la `Request` y usas el método `all` que proporciona dicha clase, estás bajo el peligro que el usuario provea información no esperada dentro de dicha `Request`, ¿a qué me refiero con esto? Qué en algún momento dado la petición contenga un campo `is_admin` o algo por el estilo, modifique este campo dentro de tu modelo y por ende el usuario se registre como administrador sin permiso de nadie (hay que tener en cuenta que esto es muy raro que pase, pero siempre existe la posibilidad).

Mitigar este tipo de problemas es muy fácil en Laravel:

- Usar la propiedad `$guarded` dentro del modelo para evitar cualquier asignación masiva de las columnas especificadas (mi opción personal);
- Usar la propiedad `$fillable` dentro del modelo para especificar los campos únicos para asignación masiva;
- Validar el request (justo como lo estás haciendo);

Una forma segura sería de la siguiente manera:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'username'=> 'required',
        'rol'=> 'required',
        'status' => 'required',
        'email'=> 'required|unique:users',
        'password'=> 'required',
    ]);

    $user = new App\User();
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->username = $request->username;
    $user->rol = $request->rol;
    $user->status = $request->status;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password); // Se encripta la contraseña usando la función bcrypt().
    $user->save(); // Se guarda el registro en la base de datos.

    return redirect()->route('users.index')
                     ->with('success','User created successfully.');
}
```

De esta manera nosotros controlamos exactamente que se le asigna al usuario.

---

> ¿que debo colocar para que me cifre el password?

Simplemente usar la función helper que provee Laravel:

```
$encryptedPassword = bcrypt($password);
```

---

Puedes revisar la siguiente información para darte una idea más completa:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/encryption
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Acabo de probar,registro y cifro la contraseña sin problemas!!!

MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente tienes que usar el facade Hash para "encriptar" la contraseña, con su método make:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

Hash::make($data['password']);
```

Puedes ver más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing#basic-usage